# How to Query Across Log Analytics and Application Insights in Azure Monitor

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55133921/5139495) summarizes that App Insights (AI) and Log Analytics (LA) are being merged into one service. It also provides a suggestion that new resources in AI can point at LA, so that all your code is in one place.

My question is how can I query across LA and AI resources, given that both exist, and you don't have the time or permissions to change the AI to point at LA.

Using Azure Workbooks I realised I can query from multiple resources inside LA or AI, but I don't seem to be able to query across LA and AI in one cell (nor save results between cells.)

At present the only ways I can think to solve this are to query through the API or joining in a PBI report, but both of these are massive overhead to complete exploratory querying. Is there an easier way, ideally whilst staying inside Kusto queries?

Comment: yes, in workbooks you're limited to picking multiple of the same "type" of thing, like workspace or app insights resource. but as @KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT points out in their answer, you can use the `workspace` and `app` syntax inside the query to query between the types.  its a little more complicated because you need that info in the query text, but you could still get that info in workbooks in parameters to keep things a little simpler

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/query-language) is your one-stop shop for querying across cross-resources.

> Previously with Azure Monitor, you could only analyze data from within
> the current workspace, and it limited your ability to query across
> multiple workspaces defined in your subscription. Additionally, you
> could only search telemetry items collected from your web-based
> application with Application Insights directly in Application Insights
> or from Visual Studio. This also made it a challenge to natively
> analyze operational and application data together.
>
> Now you can query not only across multiple Log Analytics workspaces,
> but also data from a specific Application Insights app in the same
> resource group, another resource group, or another subscription. This
> provides you with a system-wide view of your data. You can only
> perform these types of queries in [Log Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/log-query-overview).

To reference another workspace in your query, use the [workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/workspace-expression) identifier, and for an app from Application Insights, use the [app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/app-expression) identifier.

For example, you can query multiple resources from any of your resource instances, these can be workspaces and apps combined like below.

```
// crossResource function that scopes my Application Insights resources
union withsource= SourceApp
app('Contoso-app1').requests, 
app('Contoso-app2').requests,
app('Contoso-app3').requests,
app('Contoso-app4').requests,
app('Contoso-app5').requests
```

Or like,

```
union Update, workspace("contosoretail-it").Update, workspace("b459b4u5-912x-46d5-9cb1-p43069212nb4").Update
| where TimeGenerated >= ago(1h)
| where UpdateState == "Needed"
| summarize dcount(Computer) by Classification
```

Or like,

```
applicationsScoping 
| where timestamp > ago(12h)
| where success == 'False'
| parse SourceApp with * '(' applicationName ')' * 
| summarize count() by applicationName, bin(timestamp, 1h) 
| render timechart
```

For details, refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/cross-workspace-query).